# Is there a way to use a GUI Debugger (PyCharm, CLion, VSCode, ...) to debug a shared library called from ctypes?

Tags: python, c++, pycharm, shared-libraries, ctypes

I am calling a .so file from ctypes in Python to do some image processing. Somewhere from within the shared libraries, the image data is being corrupted. I would like to step through the shared library code to see where the problem may be occurring.

I've tried to do some research to find a solution, but I haven't been successful. Using the PyCharm debugger for this would be most ideal, since it is needed to run the original Python code (trust me, it really is needed). I've written the C++ code in VSCode, so using that as a debugger is also an option. I'm also willing to purchase CLion if it will solve my problem.

Comment: If your IDE is giving you trouble, why don't you simply use `gdb` or similar directly from the command line?

Comment: I will start by saying that I'm not very familiar with `gdb` and if it's only usable through the command line, I won't be able to use it for image processing as I need to be able to see structured arrays visually to see how the pixel values change as the program progresses.

Comment: You can use `gdb` from the command line to debug graphics programs. Why would your text view into the code prevent the program from having a graphical representation?

Comment: in VSCode put the python binary file as your executable target and pass your ctypes script as an arhument to it. By starting to debug the C++ code, the python code will be executed and u can go through your C++ .so code.

Comment: There is another option as well. I am not sure about VSCode, but can its debugger attach to a running process? If yes, put a short delay at the beginning of your C++ method, then run the python script. Finally attach the debugger to the running Python process.